# Collapse Pandas dataframe to yield a non-redundant column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that looks something like this.

```
>>> df
  Chrom       Pos  Score
4  chr3  14166653  5.164
3  chr3   3120477  3.892
1  chr1   2448046  3.783
2  chr2  41642884  3.285
0  chr1  53486837  1.671
```

It is sorted on the `Score` column. I'd like to collapse the dataframe so that the `Chrom` column is non-redundant. More specifically, the result should contain only the highest scoring row for each distinct value in the `Chrom` column. The result should look like this.

```
>>> df
  Chrom       Pos  Score
4  chr3  14166653  5.164
1  chr1   2448046  3.783
2  chr2  41642884  3.285
```

How would I do this in a concise and efficient way?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('Chrom')`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the one-liner and for pointing me to the other thread!

Comment: Yup, since it was already sorted it was that simple. Otherwise, just add a .`sort_values` before.